# Access unnamed control in xaml from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I've got about 20 of the following underneath a `ComboBox` (which means that I can't use any `x:Name` parameter due to duplicate naming):

```
<ComboBoxItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="folder/someimage.png" Height="20" Width="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="SampleText" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

How can I access the string from the `TextBlock` inside the `SelcetionChanged` event?

Currently when I choose the item normally, the selected text (of my `ComboBox`) is set to

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem

This is the return value from the `ComboBoxItem.ToString()` method!

How can I change the return type of my `xaml` based `ComboBoxItem`?

Comment: When you fill that Combo from XAML you _can_ use `x:Name`. What would be the problem?

Comment: @HenkHolterman If I'd use `x:Name="txt"` for example to access it from behind as `comboBox.SelectedItem = txt.Text;` this would work for the first item, but all others will fail due to **duplicate naming** (only one `TextBlock` can be named `txt` --> **does not work**

Comment: `txt1`...`txt2`...`txt3`...

Comment: Inserting the chunk of xaml by 20 times? Consider applying MVVM as Henk suggests. Btw if you make a inheritance of `ComboBox`, you can override `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I've found a solution. I've created a new `UserControl` and then added it as item of my `ComboBox`.

**MyComboBoxItem.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Image, ElementName=myComboBoxItem}" Height="18" Width="18"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=myComboBoxItem}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MyComboBoxItem.xaml.cs:**

```
public string Text
{
    get { return txt.Text; }
    set { txt.Text = value; }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return Text;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<ComboBox>
    <local:MyComboBoxItem Image="image1.png" Text="Item1"/>
    <local:MyComboBoxItem Image="image2.png" Text="Item2"/>
    <local:MyComboBoxItem Image="image3.png" Text="Item3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Now it works like a charm and does exactly what I've wanted.